# Session data gets lost after posting form from external webpage

Tags: php, forms, session, session-cookies, external

I have a form pushing details to an external webpage from example.com to externalexample.com

`<form id="frmCheckout" method="post" role="form" action="https://externalexample.com/test.php">`

On the external webpage I also have a form

`<form method="post" action="https://example.com/frm.php">`

If I do it quick my sessions will remain on mydomain.com but if I wait for like 2 minutes my session is gone on mydomain.com.
I also tested it out by instead of posting doing a direct link to mydomain.com, but then my session remains, also tested form method GET and my session also remains on mydomain.com.
So the problem is there only after waiting a short while and posting a form with POST.

My session is set with the following code (this is the most top code, so no output before session_start()

```
<?php
$Lifetime = 3600;
$DirectoryPath = '/var/www/example.com/html/session';

is_dir($DirectoryPath) or mkdir($DirectoryPath, 0777);

if (ini_get("session.use_trans_sid") == true) {
    ini_set("url_rewriter.tags", "");
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", false);

}

ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $Lifetime);
ini_set("session.gc_divisor", "1");
ini_set("session.gc_probability", "1");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", $Lifetime);
ini_set("session.save_path", $DirectoryPath);


session_name('mydomain-v1');
session_start();
```

I also tried without the ini_set and using the default session but that also doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what the cause is, but in case the session is remembered using a cookie, you might want to check the presence of that cookie. Also remember that it might be your browser that deletes the cookie.

Comment: It happens in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It's a regular session what you can inspect inside the chrome dev tools under Application --> Cookies. And note it is only with POST submits from external, nog GET submits.